# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement while enter date and save into access why?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have this code:

```
Public Sub insert_item(ByVal mydate As Date)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into shop1 (date) values (@mydate)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydate'", OleDbType.Date).Value = mydate
```

and when it runs I get this error:

![this is my problem][1]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try changing your query to this: `"INSERT INTO shop1 ([date]) VALUES (?)"`... `Date` is reserved and the parameters names do not matter as well.

Comment: date is a keyword.  Put it in [brackets].

Answer (score -1):

OleDB does't really do named parameters. You use `?` characters as the placeholders in the SQL string. You should also create a new connection object for each query, and only keep it open for the minimum time possible; typically this is done via the `Using` keyword:

```
Public Sub insert_item(ByVal mydate As Date)
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into shop1 (date) values (?)", con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydate'", OleDbType.Date).Value = mydate
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```